# passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField:'email'},User.authenticate())); TypeError: User.authenticate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();

    ******    
const passport=require('passport');
const LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;


//requiring user route
const userRoutes=require('./routes/users');

//requiring user model

const User=require('./models/usermodel');
dotenv.config({path:'./config.env'});

//middleware for session
  ***********   
//passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

the below 3 lines show a error that, "authenticate" is not a function

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField:'email'},User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

after removing above 3 lines the server starts but do not get authentication

here is the usermodel file

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const passportLocalMongoose=require('passport-local-mongoose');

let userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    email:String,
    password:{
        type:String,
        select:false
    }
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose,{usernameField:'email'});

module.exports=mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
```

Comment: Can you do a console log `console.log('User: ', User);` after this line `const User=require('./models/usermodel');` to see what does user variable contain.

Comment: And maybe you should put the content of `./models/usermodel` in the answer to see what's in there...

Comment: try this: 
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

Comment: still not working